# Are big LUKS file containers a bad idea?

Tags: luks

I have 150 GB in files to back-up (on an external HDD). Could I just create a 150 GB LUKS container? Or would it be a better idea to create 5x30 GB, or 10x15 GB? Besides making a backup of the header, what should I do to make sure the files in the LUKS container will always be accessible?

Comment: By container, do you mean a 150GB file inside an existing filesystem, or a regular partition?

Comment: @frostschutz Inside a partition there is a LUKS volume. For the filesystem it's a file among other files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant container files...

The downside of such containers is that their survival depends on the outer filesystem. Files that large usually end up using several fragments; if you ever lose the outer filesystem to any kind of corruption, you won't be able to recover the containers either, even if the raw data of those containers is still intact. Without knowing where the individual fragments are located, you're looking at an unsolvable puzzle. (Finding the LUKS header in the raw data will only give you the first piece.)

That's not to mention bugs or accidents where such container files might be deleted or truncated... which is usually not possible to recover, either.

Also, all writes are passed through the outer filesystem which might impact performance a bit.

There are better alternatives out there, such as LVM which lets you create volumes of arbitrary sizes, unfragmented, and it keeps metadata backups and history so even if you were to lose a logical volume somehow, you have some chances of recovery.

> Besides making a backup of the header, what should I do to make sure the files in the LUKS container will always be accessible?

`filefrag` can tell you the *what's-where* of individual files... if you're going to backup the header, you might also want to backup your partition tables and use filefrag to get a list of the physical file extents for manual recovery...

Comment: So, would it be a good idea to create an independent LUKS partition instead of container files? And a corresponding partition for backup?